# How to impute columns value in one dataframe from that of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 & df2 as below. I need to replace "unknown" in df1 by the corresponding value in df2. Both df1 & df2 have same column name "FIRST NAME" and "gender", while df1 have more rows with repeated value, as well as other columns which are not shown here. I wrote code as below, but error thrown out. How to fix it? Thanks!

```
df1['gender'] = df1['gender'][df1['gender']=='unknown'].map(df2.set_index('FIRST_NAME')['gender'])

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please tell me if my solution works

Comment: I tried first two, but not working. InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: `df1['gender'] = df1['FIRST NAME'].map(df2.drop_duplicates().set_index('FIRST NAME')['gender']).where(m,df1['gender'])` check section DUPLICATES VALUES of my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Series.map` with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
m = df1['gender'].eq('unknown')
df1.loc['gender',m] = df1.loc[m,'FIRST NAME'].map(df2.set_index('FIRST NAME')['gender'])
```

or [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
df1['gender'] = df1['FIRST NAME'].map(df2.set_index('FIRST NAME')['gender']).where(m,df1['gender'])
```

**DUPLICATES VALUES**

if there are duplicates values in `df2['FIRST NAME']` you need use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) 
**if both gender and FIRST NAME are repeated:**

```
df1['gender'] = df1['FIRST NAME'].map(df2.drop_duplicates().set_index('FIRST NAME')['gender']).where(m,df1['gender'])
```

if for the same first Name there are different genders needed then use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1 = df1[['FIRST NAME']].merge(df2,on ='FIRST NAME',how = 'left')
```